# Difference between two timestamps to be returned in the format d:h:m:s in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two timestamp columns and I want to get the difference between them in this format:
5days 3hours 24minutes 30seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this mysql code:

```
SELECT concat(floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now())/(3600*24)),'days ',
              floor((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now())/(3600*24))*3600*24))/3600),'hours ',
              floor((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now())/(3600*24))*3600*24))/3600)*3600))/60),'minutes ',
              (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now()) - (floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`timevalue`,now())/(3600*24))*3600*24))/3600)*3600))/60)*60)),'seconds ') 
FROM `time_tbl`
```

Here `time_tbl` is your table name and `timevalue` is your attribute name. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
SECOND ,  '2012-06-06 15:20:18',  '2012-06-09 13:13:55' ) )
```

try this you can get **hh:mm:ss** value

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(
 FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46:00', '2010-01-01 12:30:20')) / 24), ' days ',
 MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46:00', '2010-01-01 12:30:20')), 24), ' hours ',
 MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46:00', '2010-01-01 12:30:20')), ' minutes ',
 SECOND(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46:00', '2010-01-01 12:30:20')),' seconds') as dif
```

There is nothing inbuilt like this in mysql. Replace your tiemstamp values wherever required.